# Running macros one after another in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have 3 macros, and I want to have them executed in a very precise order. My code is currently as below:

```
Sub MasterFindAndReplace()
    Call BulkFindTermsWithCase
    Call BulkFindTerms
    Call BulkFindReplace
End Sub
```

With this code, will the macros run **successively**, or will they run **simultaneously**?

If this code will result in all macro executed at the same time/in random order, is there any way I can make it runs like so: *BulkFindTermsWithCase -> BulkFindTerms -> Call BulkFindReplace*

Comment: If you step through the code using F8, you'll see that the macros are called consecutively, and in that order.

Comment: Nice! I never knew there's such a function. Thanks, mate!

Comment: You're very welcome.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done natively with VBA. VBA is built in a single-threaded apartment. The only way to get multiple threads is to build a DLL in something other than VBA that has a COM interface and call it from VBA. Of course, if you do have multiple processor cores in your computer (which is commonplace nowadays), your program can use threads to take advantage of additional cores to perform your processing, and you will see a speedup, because you are throwing more horsepower at your computing problem. If you don't use threads at all, your program will only utilize a single processor core, which is fine if that's all you need.